# How can I extract a url from a directory full of garbage using a regexp?

Tags: regex

I have thousands of files I downloaded text files of and they all follow the same pattern.  The pattern seemed to work in a parser (and notepad++) but when I try to find it on the console and then ultimately want to pipe it to wget for downloading, I get `grep: Invalid range end`

`grep -E "\(https://foo.domain.com/([A-z])\w+.pdf\)" * > wget`

I am unfamiliar with proper wildcarding, as I tried `.*` or similiar, escaping the forward slashes to all no avail.  I am sure it is something stupid.

Essentially everything is correct except there is a random string of text between the .com/zzz.pdf

Comment: Provide example of any source text, escaped parentheses is required?

Comment: grep -oP "https:\/\/foo\.domain\.com\/[A-z]+\w+\.pdf" | wget -i -

Comment: @sparse Can you post as an answer, while I had to do additional steps in vi, (it added prefixed items and duplicate lines) but was trivial enough to fix and allowed me to use wget -i from a file rather than piping, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

By default, *grep* matches case-sensitively, therefore you *must* end any range with a character *following* the range start.

1. This is invalid: `[A-z]` (because lower case z comes before upper case A)
2. This is valid: `[A-Z]` (because upper case Z comes after upper case A)
3. This is valid: `[a-z]` (because lower case z comes after lower case a)

I suspect you meant to write the third one (meaning all your matched URLs start with lower case)

The pattern may have worked in a different environment because that was configured to match case-insensitively, or, more likely, with a different collation order (try `LC_COLLATE=C grep 'A-z'`).

Comment: The file names are all random cased, so it may be AzRRjkL.pdf for example.  The length of the file name isn't fixed.  So I just need to redirect what grep finds to wget for download.

Answer (score 0):

`grep -oP "https:\/\/foo\.domain\.com\/[A-z]+\w+\.pdf" | wget -i -`